# convert xml to csv python

Tags: python, xml

New to python,I am presently in the process of converting the XML to CSV using Python 3.6.1

Input file is file1.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package>
    <name>AllFeatureRules</name>
    <pkgId>13569656</pkgId>
    <pkgMetadata>
        <creator>rsikhapa</creator>
        <createdDate>13-05-2018 10:07:16</createdDate>
        <pkgVersion>3.0.29</pkgVersion>
        <application>All</application>
        <icType>Feature</icType>
        <businessService>Common</businessService>
        <technology>All,NA</technology>
        <runTimeFormat>RBML</runTimeFormat>
        <inputForTranslation></inputForTranslation>
        <pkgDescription></pkgDescription>
    </pkgMetadata>
    <rules>
        <rule>
            <name>ip_slas_scheduling</name>
            <ruleId>46288</ruleId>
            <ruleVersion>1.3.0</ruleVersion>
            <ruleVersionId>1698132</ruleVersionId>
            <nuggetId>619577</nuggetId>
            <nuggetVersionId>225380</nuggetVersionId>
            <icType>Feature</icType>
            <creator>paws</creator>
            <customer></customer>
        </rule>
 </rules>
    <versionChanges>
        <rulesAdded/>
        <rulesModified/>
        <rulesDeleted/>
    </versionChanges>
</Package>
```

python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("file1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

get_range = lambda col: range(len(col))
l = [{r[i].tag:r[i].text for i in get_range(r)} for r in root]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)

df.to_csv('ABC.csv')
```

python code written as above

problem is it is taking csv conversion only for parent element(pkgmetadata) not for  child element(rules).
 ,
not converting all xml file into csv .please let me know solution

Comment: Have you considered [`xmltodict`](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/xmltodict.html)?

Comment: "please let me know solution" Sure, once you tell us what the problem is

Comment: problem is it is taking csv conversion only for parent element(pkgmetadata) not for  child element(rules).

Comment: Thanks alecxe , i used same , working fine

Answer (score 0):

to iterate over every entry, you can use the element trees `ET.iter()` function.

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("file1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
iter_root = root.iter()

l = {}
for elem in iter_root:
    l[str(elem.tag)] = str(elem.text)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l,orient="index")

df.to_csv('ABC.csv')
```

producing a csv:

```
;0
Package;"
    "
name;ip_slas_scheduling
pkgId;13569656
pkgMetadata;"
        "
creator;paws
createdDate;13-05-2018 10:07:16
pkgVersion;3.0.29
application;All
icType;Feature
businessService;Common
technology;All,NA
runTimeFormat;RBML
inputForTranslation;None
pkgDescription;None
rules;"
        "
rule;"
            "
ruleId;46288
ruleVersion;1.3.0
ruleVersionId;1698132
nuggetId;619577
nuggetVersionId;225380
customer;None
versionChanges;"
        "
rulesAdded;None
rulesModified;None
rulesDeleted;None
```